# Export fans of a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-pages, export

Is it possible to export the fans list?
If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Facebook fans cannot be exported.

However, it would be better if you could explain what you mean by exporting. Are you looking for a sort of contact list out the page fans?

Comment: exactly, i want to have a list of persons, preferably ordered by the like time